# three.js add pointlights to camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

Well here is my code I'm trying to add 2 lights on the camera so that they move along with the usage of orbitcontrols. For a reason unknown to me the lights / spheres are not visible. Could someone point out what am I doing wrong here?

```
var sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2000, 16, 16), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000}) );
var cameraLight1 = new THREE.PointLight( this.options.lights.lightColor, this.options.lights.lightIntensity * 1.2, this.options.lights.lightRadious );

    sphere1.add( cameraLight1 );
    sphere1.position.set( -5000, -5000, -5000 );

this.camera.add( sphere1 );

var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2000, 16, 16), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000}) );
var cameraLight2 = new THREE.PointLight( this.options.lights.lightColor, this.options.lights.lightIntensity * 1.2, this.options.lights.lightRadious );

    sphere2.add( cameraLight2 );    
    sphere2.position.set( -5000, -5000, -5000 );

this.camera.add( sphere2 );
```

If I add the spheres/lights in the scene instead they appear fine.
No idea why this doesn't work

PS:

camera initial position: `{x: 0, y: 5.510910596163089e-12, z: 90000}`

**update**

this doesn't work also:

```
var cameraLight1 = new THREE.PointLight( this.options.lights.lightColor, this.options.lights.lightIntensity * 1.2, this.options.lights.lightRadious );

this.camera.add( cameraLight1 );
    cameraLight1.position.set( 0,0,-5000 );

var cameraLight2 = new THREE.PointLight( this.options.lights.lightColor, this.options.lights.lightIntensity * 1.2, this.options.lights.lightRadious );

this.camera.add( cameraLight2 );
    cameraLight2.position.set( 0,0,-5000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add child objects to the camera, you must also add the camera to the scene. Otherwise, the child objects will not be part of the scene graph.

```
scene.add( camera ); // this is required...
camera.add( light ); // ... whenever you do this
```

three.js r.69

Comment: the camera is being added to the scene before any lights or spheres are added to it.